# Set bit counting

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Hi I am trying to analyze a function

```
int countBit(uint32_t n) {
    n = (n & 0x55555555) + ((n & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1);
    n = (n & 0xC30C30C3) + ((n & 0x0C30C30C) >> 2) + ((n & 0x30C30C30) >> 4);
    return n % 63;
}
```

Now I've already figured out that it counts the number of set bits (originally the function name has been different so it was not obvious.)

I also know that the line

```
n = (n & 0x55555555) + ((n & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1);
```

gives the number of 1 in subsequent pairs. However after that I am at lost. Individually I know what the code is doing, but I do not know why it does that and what is the idea behind it.

Comment: why not simplify it down to a single byte and work through it

Comment: @pm100 Because it takes longer.

Comment: See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel for an explanation. You'll have to study the code a bit, and refer to the links presented at the bottom of that section.

Comment: I already read through the seander before i posted this question, maybe not really thoroughly, but I still do not understand this version of the algorithm. And i was hoping for a conscise explanation of the idea behind it without spend few more hour on this problem. I already worked through the problem on a single 32 bit number with hope it would clarify something for me, however I was only able to see that it does indeed work but gained no deeper understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I haven't seen this one before.  It's pretty clever, although I wonder how fast the modulus is compared to more bit twiddling.

Anyway, after `n = (n & 0x55555555) + ((n & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1)`, we have 16 2-bit counts.

`(n & 0xC30C30C3)` isolates the 6 counts that are shifted by multiples of 6 bits, i.e., multiplied by multiples of 64.  Since 64%63 = 1, taking the modulus mod 63 will add all of these together.  `+ ((n & 0x0C30C30C) >> 2)` isolates the counts that are shifted by 6k+2 bits, and adds them to the above. `+ ((n & 0x30C30C30) >> 4)` does the same for counts that are shifted by 6k+4 bits.  After those additions we have 6 5-bit counters that the `%63` can add together all at once.

Comment: (Ever wondered whether it works for `n = (n & 0x33333333) + ((n & (0x33333333 << 2)) >> 2); return n % 15;`?)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why mod 63 ads the bit count?

Comment: @Want_to_be_unknown (A*64^2 + B*64 + C) % 63 = (A*(64^2%63)+B*(64%63)+C)%63 = (A*1 + B*1 +C)%63

Comment: @greybeard the count goes up to 32, which would overflow in %15